# Regex not always working with angle brackets

Tags: java, regex

So, in the process of writing a Brainfuck translator in Java I need to split the string following next rules: any of the `[ ] , .` characters or any sequence of the `+ - < >` should be followed by newline. Here's the input string:

```
..-<[-]>..[[<<[+[-<-->>+,>-.++]-,>,<[.],][<.,<-]+[-,<->,-]<<[>->-.<-[.<++,>++,].-]]]
```

And my code:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\+|-|<|>)+", "$0\n")
.replaceAll("\\.|\\,|\\[|\\]", "$0\n");
```

And the result (SO won't allow this here): https://pastebin.com/ZaT8d5ve
What was expected: https://pastebin.com/gNxcgTSP
It seems that connections of brackets with plus-minus signs are faulty, while angle brackets with square brackets and dot/comma are fine. I can't really get, what's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output does exactly what you described, sequence of the `+` `-` `<` `>` is followed by `\n` so `-<` becomes `-<\n` not `-\n<\n`.

If I understand you correctly you want to split of sequence of *same characters* which is either `+` `-` `<` `>` to have `\n` after it. If that is the case then instead of

```
s.replaceAll("(\\+|-|<|>)+", "$0\n")
```

you can use

```
s.replaceAll("(\\+|-|<|>)\\1*", "$0\n")
```

`\1` is backreference to match from group 1 (here `(\\+|-|<|>)`), so it matches one of those characters and its optional following repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that

```
(\\+|-|<|>)+
```

would match only sequences of identical characters like `++` whereas it also matches any sequence of these characters like `-<-->>`.

You also don't need two regexes in sequence. The following should do:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([+<>-])\\1*|[,.\\[\\]]", "$0\n");
```